# Django - Passing a json or an array in URL for an API call

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-urls

I want to pass a number off variables (either as a JSON or Array) via an API, such as:

```
{'age': 35, 'gender':'female', ...etc}
```

I am not sure how to pass this information into the Djano URL.  I could set up individual parameters in the URL, but I got quite a few to pass.  there must be an easier way of doing it

SOLUTION:
Solved by switching of a POST Call in the API and setting up the serializers for each variable so that they can be passed through the request.

Comment: Use the POST method instead of GET. you can send data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using axios to make calls from django backend. In my case I can do:

**js.file:**

```js
function search(token, status, q) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(start(token));
        axios
            .get(`${serverIP}/invoices/sales-invoice/`, {
                params: {
                    status: status,
                    q: q,
                },
            })
            .then((res) => {
                dispatch(successSearch(res.data, status));
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                dispatch(fail(err));
            });
    };
}
```

Here I am sending 2 params, but you can actually send object, for example user info.
And than in views get them

**views.py:**

```py
def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        status = request.query_params.get('status')
        q= request.query_params.get('q')
```

These is exapmple with DRF model viewset

Comment: Thanks!  That has set me on the right course of solving the issue.